# Does the server certificate control the cipher suites available to secure the communications?

Tags: encryption, tls

If a CA signs a certificate with a SHA1 signature hash algorithm, does that mean a client would be unable to communicate with the server if TLS 1.0 and below is disabled?

I think what I'm asking is if the identification of the server and the encryption of the communications is limited by the certificate of the server.

Let me know if you need additional details to help clarify my question.

Comment: Please do not use uppercase with abbreviations for standard terms. It gets very confusing.

Comment: Note that until TLS1.3 -- 3 years after this Q -- TLS ciphersuites were only weakly linked to protocol version. The key _in_ the certificate did affect ciphersuites in 1.0-1.2, but not protocol. The signature _on_ the certificate did not affect either (and still does not post-2018).

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no restriction coming from the TLS protocol version with regards to the hash function used by a CA in its signature algorithm.

In TLS 1.2 the client can advertise both the signature algorithms and the hash functions that it supports; this is done in the [`signature_algorithms`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.4.1) extension, which is optional. A given client may perfectly well send such an extension stating that SHA-1 is supported as part of RSA / DSA / ECDSA signatures. Actually, if the client does *not* send the extension, then the server is supposed to assume that the client supports SHA-1.

In SSL/TLS versions prior to TLS 1.2 (thus up to, and including, TLS 1.1), there is no such extension: the client does not indicate what hash functions it supports.

In practice, a server usually has only one certificate at its disposal, and will send it, regardless of how that certificate was signed by its issuing CA: the client will accept the certificate, or not, but the server does not have anything better to send anyway.

---

Google and Microsoft currently appear to want to wage a war on SHA-1 (in fact Google started it, and Microsoft must follow so as not to seem lagging and irresponsible), but this is not related to the TLS protocol version.

Comment: Actually NIST started it; SP800-57 in 2005 'required' 112-bit strength (minimum SHA-224, RSA-2048, DSA&DH-2048/224) as of 2011. (Scarequotes because IIRC FISMA didn't make NIST non-FIPS pubs legally mandatory until later.) But FIPS186-3 standardizing DSA>1024/160 wasn't approved until 2009, and in 2011 implementors hadn't all upgraded, so SP800-131A allowed a 3-year grace period where SHA1 RSA-1024 DSA&DH-1024/160 were 'deprecated' but not 'disallowed'. CABforum agreed with requiring RSA-2048 as of 2014 and I recall lots of hurried reissuances then, but was somewhat laxer on SHA2 -- ...

Comment: I don't recall their exact wording but it was something like "CAs must switch from SHA1 to SHA2 as soon as a sufficient fraction of browsers support it". This let the browser-makers, yes including MS and google, drive the timing of SHA2 over 2014 and 2015 and IIRC pretty well into 2016. And then in 2017 CWI, with resources from google, broke SHA1 for collision at cost 2^63.1.